# Remove records from table which id does not exist in a list, keep existing and insert those not in the table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have been thinking a way to do what the topic suggests:
Assume that I am given an array list of integers, e.g. 1, 3, 5, and in a table like the following I have certain records existing:

```
categoryid     userid
1              2
2              2
3              2
```

Which ***categoryid*** and ***userid*** together form the primary key. And with the array list given by user with id = 2, I want to remove records with categoryid that are not in the list, which is 2. And then keep those are in the list, which is 3, finally insert those are not in the table yet, i.e. 5. And the table after the operation will looks like the following:

```
categoryid     userid
1              2
3              2
5              2
```

Is there better way to do this other than simply remove all records with userid = 2, and insert new records according to the array list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to do two main operations `DELETE` and `INSERT`. you cannot do these in one query, so you want at least two queries. in the other hand you can write your sql query for delete and insert in a smart way that all deletions is done in just one query (by using OR for different values) and also insertion in one batch query.